# can we connect elastic search cluster running on EC2 as a datasource for aws appSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, aws-appsync

I have an ec2 cluster in which my ES is running. I want to use AWS app sync, can I connect that as a data source to it. If so how?
Or is it tightly coupled to use with Amazon OpenSearch Service?

Comment: are you asking about Elasticsearch or opensearch, as they are different products

Comment: In ec2 I have elastic search running not OpenSearch, I want to connect them as a data source. OR is it app sync tightly coupled with OpenSearch